# How to get QComboBox Item data

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qcombobox

Instead of using `.addItem("Item Name", "My Data")` to populate the `QComboBox`

I create its item first:

`item = QtGui.QStandardItem("Item Name")`

Then I set item's data:

`item.setData("My data")`

Question. How to get the data stored in Combo's Item from inside of `currentIndexChanged()` method which gets the clicked ComboBox item's index as an argument:

```
import sys
import PySide.QtCore as QtCore
import PySide.QtGui as QtGui

class MyCombo(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        vLayout=QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(vLayout)

        self.combo=QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.currentIndexChanged)
        comboModel=self.combo.model()
        for i in range(3):
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(i))
            item.setData('MY DATA' + str(i) )
            comboModel.appendRow(item)
        vLayout.addWidget(self.combo)

    def currentIndexChanged(self, index):
        print index        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyCombo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: redundant question, you got the answer already a few days ago here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31998023/qcombobox-and-app-setstylecleanlooks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class MyCombo(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        vLayout=QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(vLayout)

        self.combo=QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.currentIndexChanged)
        comboModel=self.combo.model()
        for i in range(3):
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(i))
            comboModel.appendRow(item)
            self.combo.setItemData(i,'MY DATA' + str(i))
        vLayout.addWidget(self.combo)

    def currentIndexChanged(self, index):
        print self.combo.itemData(index)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyCombo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This should work for you i think

Answer (score 2):

Working solution is posted below.
While using `item.setData()` method we should specify a `Role` with which we associate the data.

```
class MyCombo(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        vLayout=QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(vLayout)

        self.combo=QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.currentIndexChanged)
        comboModel=self.combo.model()
        for i in range(3):
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(i))
            item.setData('MY DATA' + str(i), QtCore.Qt.UserRole )
            comboModel.appendRow(item)
        vLayout.addWidget(self.combo)

    def currentIndexChanged(self, index):     
        modelIndex=self.combo.model().index(index,0)
        print self.combo.model().data(modelIndex, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyCombo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```